# Visiting daily scrums - dos and don'ts

Tags: scrum, agile, daily-scrum

When you visit one of the daily scrums whilst being in a role *above* those scrums, do you usually participate as a beholder or, do you also speak like all scrum team members: What did you do yesterday and what are you going to do today?

If so, why and how do you describe the things which are not yet to be broadcasted to the whole team (for example, preparation of reorganisation, issues with stakeholders and anything else that everyone does not need to know [yet])?

Answer (score 10):

### You can attend and listen in the Daily Scrum but not speak

From the [Scrum Guide - The Scrum Master enforces the rule that only Development Team members participate in the Daily Scrum.](http://www.scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html#events-daily)

[From Mike Cohn's blog on the Daily Scrum Meeting](http://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/agile/scrum/daily-scrum) - ...many teams enforce a rule in which only those who are committed are allowed to talk during the daily scrum meeting.
All team members are required to attend scrum meetings. Since both the ScrumMaster and product owner are committed team members, they are expected to attend and participate. Anyone else (for example, a departmental VP, a salesperson or a developer from another project) is allowed to attend, but is there only to listen. This makes scrum meetings an excellent way for a Scrum team to disseminate information -- if you're interested in hearing where things are at, attend that day's meeting.

The purpose of the Daily Scrum meeting is for the team to share with their team mates progress of work and planning for that day. And it is tightly time boxed. So, the entire focus should be on the Sprint backlog and on the people who are doing the work.

One departmental supervisor (who manages 4 Scrum teams and other staff) I know holds a fortnightly all hands to share plans, admin matters and so on. You might want to consider something along those lines.

Comment: Many thanks for precise andswer. But in many companies there is a culture of expectation for anyone senior attending scrum to talk about what he or she did too and if you don't then it would be considered that you did not do anything. And my question is partially on this psychology part as opposed to Scrum Guide wording.

Comment: Edited my answer above with additional info.

Comment: Great answer. To G33k's comment, you can think of it this way. The scrum is a tactical meeting for the team to work out together how they're going to work toward their sprint goals for the next day. To create an analogy, if a football defensive team were talking on the sidelines before taking the field and the head coach was there, it might be fine to point out a common opening in the opposing team's offense. Discussing what he and the offensive coach we're planning for their next possession would not be relevant and just waste time.

Answer (score 0):

As a sr mgr and manager of the scrum masters I encourage a separation between the Standup (chickens and pigs, team talks everyone else observes) and the "after" conversation time, when I might share my updates or answer questions. Keeping the standup by the team, for the team, I think sends the right message - you are responsible figuring out how to achieve your goals, and for surfacing impediments. With Scrum Masters supporting, it gets to be a pretty easy habit for even the most caffeinated non-team members to hold their fire for 5 - 10 min, then jump in.

Answer (score 0):

Our organization relies heavily on GA asset development (we create simulations), so we include them in the daily scrums. Some are technically inclined (i.e. understand code) while others are not. Nonetheless, the GA work needs to integrate with the code so there are dependencies, technical constraints, etc. that need to be communicated and vetted.

It is not uncommon for other non-technical talent to be included in the daily scrums, such as content developers and QA. My rule of thumb is that if an individual has a card in play on the scrum board, they're included in the daily scrums.

Comment: Does GA stand for Geographic Information Systems (GIS) Analyst?

Comment: GA == Graphic Artist. Apologies for the industry-speak.